# CSV file processing Windows script, best tools, easiest aproach?

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

On a Windows platform, using the fewest tools possible (prefer to use only built in tools such as CMD but I realize something like sed may be required); I would like create a script that will perform as follows.

It should input a csv file, extract certain fields from that file and then output a new and uniquely formatted output csv file that contains the extracted fields. For example.

```
Input.csv
Cust#, CustFName, CustLName, Address, City, State, Zip, Order#, Qty, Part, Cost, Total,,,,

Output.csv
,,, Qty, City,,,, CustFName,,, Total,,, Zip,,,
```

The csv files will vary the number of records. Some will have 3 records and others will have 10,000 records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBscript, that should be available on almost all Windows systems since Win2K. Here is an example, assuming you don't have "quoted" commas.

```
Dim fso, f2, ts, ts2, line, records
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tf1 = fso.OpenTextFile("infile.txt", ForReading, false)
Set tf2 = fso.OpenTextFile("outfile.txt", ForWriting, true)
Do While Not tf1.AtEndOfStream
    line = tf1.ReadLine
    records=Split(line,",")
    ' ... process your records here '
    line = Join(records,",")
    tf2.WriteLine line
Loop
tf1.Close
tf2.Close
```

Run this from the cmd line like "cscript yourscript.vbs". For the "real" thing, you will probably have to add some code to deal with different number of records, records where the comma is part of quoted records and so on, but the general approach should be clear.

Here is another example from the MS Win2K scripting guide:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176692.aspx